# Can Navision three tier architecture work without Kerberos?

Tags: dynamics-nav, navision

Can Navision 2009 R2, three tier architecture work without Kerberos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NAV can use workgroup authentication (where a Windows account with the same name and password exists on both the client and server) if SQL Server and the NAV Server are installed on one machine, and the client is on a second machine.

If you want to run three tiers on three computers, without Kerberos, I believe it is possible by misappropriating the features introduced for RTC over WAN. The reason that this will work is that this forces the client to be authenticated on the server machine (thus this is equivalent to the first scenario described above).

The walkthrough for Connecting the RoleTailored Client over a Wide Area Network is available on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg502476.aspx).

Alternatively, you could upgrade to NAV 2013 which introduces NAV logins similar to the SQL logins used in C/SIDE. NAV 2013 is therefore much easier to configure without Kerberos.